# How do I access Thin::Connection from inside rack middleware?

Tags: ruby, rack, thin

I would like to run `set_comm_inactivity_timeout(0)` on my EM Connection from inside Rack Middleware.

This will allow me to have one timeout for my upgraded web sockets and another for the rails app.

My web sockets are all first in the middleware chain so it is not wreaking havoc with Rack::Lock and such.

I see that some simply go for an infinite timeout in Thin and then inject something like [Rack::Timeout](https://github.com/kch/rack-timeout) after.

Is there a way to access EM::Connection or the signature of the connection from Rack middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way to do this is monkey patch thin:

```
class Thin::Connection
  alias :thin_process      :process
  def process
    set_comm_inactivity_timeout(0)
    thin_process
  end
end
```